# SIMBL not working on Snow Leopard even with apps in 32-bit mode

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard

I've been using SIMBL with the TerminalColors plugin on Leopard, after upgrading to Snow Leopard it won't work.

Someone has posted a modified plugin but this doesn't appear to work for me, its almost as if SIMBL itself isn't being loaded with my Terminal.app even with it set to 32-Bit mode.

Anyone one know how I can check if the InputManager is even being loaded?

Thanks
Rob

Answer (score 2):

SIMBL uses the InputManagers API. Apple had made it clear that ability to modify apps by patching [InputManagers](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/releasenotes/Cocoa/AppKit.html#NSInputManager) would not be supported in Leopard and would likely break in future versions of OSX. And that future is here now.

According to the developer, [SIMBL](http://www.culater.net/software/SIMBL/SIMBL.php) is being reworked as a Framework. While it might be able to support its functionality in the future, it might just lock up all your applications if it mis-fired.